# Searching for membership in array of ranges

Tags: algorithm, search

As part of our system simulation, I'm modeling a memory space with 64-bit addressing using a sparse memory array and keeping a list of objects to keep track of buffers that are allocated within the memory space.  Buffers are allocated and de-allocated dynamically.

I have a function that searches for a given address or address range within the allocated buffers to see if accesses to the memory model are in allocated space or not, and my first cut "search through all the buffers until you find a match" is slowing down our simulations by 10%.  Our UUT does a lot of memory accesses that have to be vetted by the simulation.

So, I'm trying to optimize.  The memory buffer objects contain a starting address and a length.  I'm thinking about sorting the object array by starting address at object creation, and then, when the checking function is called, doing a binary search through the array looking to see if a given address falls within a start/end range.

Are there any better/faster ways to do this?  There must be some faster/cooler algorithm out there using heaps or hash signatures or some-such, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary search through a sorted array works but makes allocation/deallocation slow.

A simple case is to make an ordered binary tree (red-black tree, AVR tree, etc.) indexed by the starting address, so that insertion (allocation), removal (deallocation) and searching are all O(log n). Most modern languages provide such data structure (e.g. C++'s `std::map`) already.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was also binary search and I think that it is a good idea. You should be able to insert and remove quickly too. Using a hash would just make you put the addresses in buckets (in my opinion) and then you'd get to the right bucket quickly (and then have to search through the bucket).

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is that you have a defined intervals of "valid" memory, memory outside those intervals is "invalid", and you want to check for a given address whether it is inside a valid memory block or not.

You can definitely do this by storing the start addresses of all allocated blocks in a binary tree; then search for the largest address at or below the queried address, and just verify that the address falls within the length of the valid address. This gives you O(log n) query time where n = number of allocated blocks. The same query of course can be used also to actually the find the block itself, so you can also read the contents of the block at the given address, which I guess you'd need also.

However, this is not the most efficient scheme. Instead, you could use additionally one-dimensional spatial subdivision trees to mark invalid memory areas. For example, use a tree with branching factor of 256 (corresponding to 8 bits) that maps all those 16kB blocks that have only invalid addresses inside them to "1" and others to "0"; the tree will have only two levels and will be very efficient to query. When you see an address, first ask form this tree if it's certainly invalid; only when it's not, query the other one. This will speed things up ONLY IF YOU ACTUALLY GET LOTS OF INVALID MEMORY REFERENCES; if all the memory references are actually valid and you're just asserting, you won't save anything. But you can flip this idea also around and use the tree mark to all those 16kB or 256B blocks that have only valid addresses inside them; how big the tree grows depends on how your simulated memory allocator works.